# Ruby on Rails | Postgres : How to find records with status (which is calculated based on has_many constraint). Please check the description

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, join, group-by

I have a listing page of schools where I have to list the name and status of the school. The status is calculated based on the student's status.

Here is my models...

```rb
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :students
  has_many :teachers
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :school

  enum status: {
    active: 'active',
    suspended: 'suspended'
  }
end
```

So, the idea is list the school name and school status as

1. school status is `active` when at least one student is in `active` state.
2. school status is `suspended` when no active student but student record exists.
3. school status is `closed` when there is no students record against school.

I am trying hard to find the query to get the data like I wanted. Since this is a `has_many` I am finding it difficult for me. I use postgresql database.

Any help will be appreciated.

Note: I need the sql query to find this. (something like combining two tables, calculating the status based on the condition)

[image]

Comment: Can you post an sample of the tables and your desired output?

Comment: I have added the pic.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over schools and count by statuses with `@school.students.group(:status).count`. It will return an ordered hash mapping statuses with their count.